# Вывод слова наибольшей длины

Tags: php, pascal

Довольно давно на школьной олимпиаде было задание (чуть ниже), написать я его на **pascal** не смог, но легко разделался с ним на **php**.
Но всё таки интересно, как бы смотрелось решение на **pascal**e

Вот сама задача:

Вводится простое повествовательное предложение (слова разделены пробелом). Вывести на экран слово наибольшей длины.
Программа должна: **а)** принять исходное предложение с клавиатуры **б)** вывести на экран слово наибольшей длины

Вот моё решение на php

```
$item = $_POST["item"];//введенное предложение  
$array = explode(" ",$item);  
$max["length"] = 0;  
$max["word"] = "";  
    for($i=0;$i < count($array);$i++)  
    {  
        if(strlen($array[$i]) > $max["length"])  
        {  
        $max["word"] = $array[$i];  
        $max["length"] = strlen($array[$i]);  
        }  
    }  
echo "Первое самое длинное слово: <b>".$max["word"]."[".$max["length"]."]</b>";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
program prog1;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
var i, ws: integer;
    sentence, wmax: string;

begin
ReadLn(sentence);
sentence := Concat(sentence, ' ');
wmax := '';
ws := 1;
for i := 1 to Length(sentence) do
  if (sentence[i] = ' ') then begin
    if (i - ws > Length(wmax)) then
      wmax := Copy(sentence, ws, i - ws);
    ws := i+1;
    end;
WriteLn(wmax);
ReadLn;
end.
```

*Delphi7, если что*

**UPD** оптимизировал немного

**UPD2** специально для автора, проверенный вариант в turbo pascal. Ищем отличия)

```
program prog1;
var i, ws: integer;
    sentence, wmax: string;

begin
ReadLn(sentence);
sentence := Concat(sentence, ' ');
wmax := '';
ws := 1;
for i := 1 to Length(sentence) do
  if (sentence[i] = ' ') then begin
    if (i - ws > Length(wmax)) then
      wmax := Copy(sentence, ws, i - ws);
    ws := i+1;
    end;
WriteLn(wmax);
ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: @oxyage, не разбрасывайтесь кармой, для этого есть слева от ответа кнопка =)

Comment: спасибо за совет и за ответ :)

и всё таки, хочется увидеть и на паскале решение

Comment: Хм, а разница?) Ну ща попробую TP откопать, проверю.

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: хм)) отличий действительно почти нет, спасибо за помощь